# Error too many redirects after set developer mode

Tags: magento2, admin, error, redirect

I have this error after set developer mode in Magento 2.

[image]

I have tried to deploy static content, clean cache, flush cache, etc...

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Check inside your `app/etc/env.php` file, to see your it's in developer mode:

```
'MAGE_MODE' => 'developer',
```

Then run these commands below to delete the generated files and generate them again.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: dont work, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands below to set your **cookie_domain** and generate all content again.

```
curl -O https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun2.phar && \
chmod +x ./n98-magerun2.phar && \
alias n98="./n98-magerun2.phar" && \
n98 config:store:set web/unsecure/base_url 'http://magento.local.com/' && \
n98 config:store:set web/secure/base_url 'http://magento.local.com/' && \
n98 config:store:set web/cookie/cookie_domain 'magento.local.com' && \
n98 setup:upgrade && \
n98 setup:static-content:deploy -f && \
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: dont work, but thanks1